# @Transactional doesn't work when fetching an image from PostreSQL with ddl-auto: update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

I have a Spring Boot app (Hibernate + JPA) and I need to fetch all courses objects from PostgreSQL. This objects also contain an image. In the DB, they are store like LOB. `@Transactional` only work on ddl-auto:create-drop.

```java
@Transactional
public List<CourseDto> getCourses() {

    List<Courses> courses = courseRepositoryDao.findAllByIsCourseFreeAndIsCourseActive(true, true);
    List<CourseDto> coursesNameDto = courses
            .stream()
            .peek(i -> i.setLogo(decompressZLib(i.getLogo())))
            .map(course -> modelMapper.map(CourseMapper.toUserDtoFreeCourses(course), CourseDto.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("**************************" + coursesNameDto + "**********************");
    return coursesNameDto;
}

// uncompress the image bytes before returning it to the angular application
public static byte[] decompressZLib(byte[] data) {
    Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
    inflater.setInput(data);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try {
        while (!inflater.finished()) {
            int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    } catch (DataFormatException e) {
    }
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

CourseMapper:

```
  @Component
public class CourseMapper {

    public static CourseDto toUserDtoFreeCourses(Courses course) {
        return new CourseDto()
                .setCourseId(course.getId())
                .setCourseName(course.getCourseName())
                .setCourseDescription(course.getCourseDescription())
                .setCoursePrice(course.getCoursePrice())
                .setIsCourseFree(course.getIsCourseFree())
                .setIsCourseActive(course.getIsCourseActive())
                .setLogo(course.getLogo());
    }
```

If I don't use @Transactional I cannot take the object from db.

How can I use @Transactional even if ddl-auto is set to update?
Why it doesn't work with "update".

When ddl-auto is on update the request from POSTMAN doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that this is related to `ddl-auto`. You do not really specify what "doesn't work" means exactly, therefore I can only  guess.

The problem might be, that you manipulate your entity in your stream cascade with `.peek(i -> i.setLogo(decompressZLib(i.getLogo())))`. This is probably not what you want. You should decompress the image in the mapping step instead, such that the uncompressed data is not written back to the `Courses` entity, but rather to `CoursesDto`.

Edit: Instead decompressing it directly in the controller, you can also do it in the mapper:

```java
.setLogo(decompressZLib(course.getLogo()))
```

For that you need to put the decompression method in the mapper as well.

Comment: Doesen't work mean that when I have ddl-auto to update, my request from fetching the courses via POSTMAN does not work. It remain in pending with the ms "Sending request..."

Comment: even with ddl-auto set to create-drop, after 2 successfuly requests, Postman crashes

Comment: if u want to make a zoom call, please tell me

Comment: only 2 request I can send through Postman, and after it remain pending on "sending request..."

Comment: I have find the problem:   .peek(i -> i.setLogo(decompressZLib(i.getLogo()))). But how can i decompress the image?

Comment: What does your CourseMapper class look like?

Comment: Eric, I have payed more attention and I have put decompress logic into Controller and now it works. Tks a lot!!! I will edit the question with CourseMapper